# How to fix invalid path without keep copying database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

i made an simple form with ms access database i clone the application to my other computer and i got this error

> Additional information: 'C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Database1.accdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

I know what the error states. my question is how can i avoid this error without keep copying and configuring the database path

Comment: Do you write any codes inside form or form control? Only copy paste never produce this types of error.

Comment: yeah i got codes inside the form like adding/removing/searching record

Comment: So, error is coming from any portion of code? If yes, then post your code so that we can look for solution.

Comment: The form don't load when debug. error is from this  `Me.Db1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.db1)`

Comment: I know i need to copy the Database1.accdb to the computer where i clone the project. but how can i avoid this error without doing that? or is it really needed to include the database1.accdb inside the project folder?

Comment: The path is also hard coded to that code? May be you have to make database path dynamic.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by hard coded as i just started to learn vb

Comment: Hard coded means, sometimes we refer file path as `myFilePath="C:\Users\XYZ\accfile.accdb` here path is hard coded. We can make it dynamic by `myFilePat=CurrentProject.Path & "\" & accfile.accdb`. In this case file is store same folder of project files.

Comment: No i don't have that kind of code. Will that fix the issue? like, if copied my project to another computer, will i still encounter the same error?

Comment: Better you ask a separate question with codes, not only one line code.

Comment: For your scenario, it is better to keep Database inside the project folder and call it accordingly.